# implemention video filter through FFMpeg in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have a video file and am trying to scale it using -vf argument for ffmpeg "Angel" repo version used in an android project.
The build through NDK is going smooth, but when I write this code, the application starts and exits. If I use any other argument other than -vf it works fine and export the video.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_schemaphic_mirrorapp_jni_NativeHelper_hFlipVideoEffect( JNIEnv *env, jstring outFile )
{
//ffplay -i INPUT -vf "crop=iw/2:ih:0:0,split[tmp],pad=2*iw[left]; [tmp]hflip[right]; [left][right] overlay=W/2"
//fmpeg -i input -vf scale=iw/2:-1 output
//ffmpeg -i input -vf yadif=0:0:0,scale=iw/2:-1  output

char** arguments;
int count = 6;

arguments = calloc( count, sizeof( char* ) );

arguments[0] = "ffmpeg";

arguments[1] = "-i";
arguments[2] = "/sdcard/mirrorapp/cropVideo.mp4";

arguments[3] = "-vf";
arguments[4] = "scale=120:-1";

//arguments[5] = "-aspect";
//arguments[6] = "3:2";
//arguments[5] = "-vcodec";
//arguments[6] = "mpeg4";
/*arguments[9] = "-r";
arguments[10] = "19";
arguments[5] = "-cropright";
arguments[6] = "240";
arguments[7] = "-padleft";
arguments[8] = "0";
arguments[9] = "-padtop";
arguments[10] = "0";
arguments[11] = "-aspect";
arguments[12] = "3:2";
arguments[13] = "-an";
arguments[5] = "-vcodec";
arguments[6] = "mpeg4";*/
//arguments[7] = "-sameq";
arguments[5] = "/sdcard/mirrorapp/cropFlipVideo.mp4";

ffmpeg_main( count, arguments );
//free(arguments);

return 1;
}
```

This gives me an impression that the set up is correct. the argument -vf is somehow not working or am not sure of the newer syntax. Kindly help.

Comment: How did you build the libraries? Specifically, when you configured the build, which filters did you enable?

Comment: probably for this kind of data manipulation you want to use OpenCV, it's probably better for AV processing.

Comment: @axis: the best option is to send the decoded video frames to OpenGL texture, so that GPU takes care of scaling and flip. But this is not a reason for ffmpeg to crash

Comment: @AlexCohn: I used the FFMpeg Angel source code from repository. I am using cygwin to create the *.so file for the libffmpeg.so. I am compile in windows xp pro and not ubuntu.

Comment: [@Deepanjan Das](http://stackoverflow.com/users/580086/deepanjan-das): I asked because I could not find standard configuration for building "Angel" with NDK 8, and maybe the **scale** filter is simply disabled in your case.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Thanks Alex, I really appreciate you quick replies. Hmm may be you are right. Actually I was trying to do hflip and when that did not work I tried doing the scale thing to see if the filter option was at all working. Then I found that the filter is not working.  So which version of ffmpeg do you suggest to use with NDK8 which has the configuration for doing the hflip.

Comment: @AlexCohn: To add more to my comments, I would like to disclose that earlier I used a lower version of ffmpeg which is below 0.8 and it worked with the crop and video padding feature with NDK, but the hflip was not working, I reviewed the ffmpeg source code to find that hflip was not there in that version, but some latest version like 0.8 have the crop, padding, hflip..etc. all under video filter. so tried Angel as it was the latest version. you might be right that the Angel might have them disabled but the configure file placed within the angel package suggests that libavfilter is enabled.

Comment: Is there a special Android configuration file in Angel? Or you downloaded it separately? Or maybe you prepared it yourself? Or took it from an earlier version? The configuration file in Angel does enable the filter, but it is not for cross compilation.

Comment: And, if the purpose is actually to render the decoded frames on an Android device, I strongly recommend to avoid the filter, but rely on hardware accelerated OpenGL for scale and orientation.

Comment: @AlexCohn: The url I used to download angel version is http://ffmpeg.org/download.html under the head >> FFmpeg 1.0 "Angel"

Comment: @AlexCohn: May be your are right for using OpenGL. Thank for your suggestion buddy, I will give it a try as well.

Comment: @DeepanjanDas Hello :D Have you succeed to do the filtering? Im trying to do the same thing, but still not working. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the answer for you:

```
arguments[3] = "-vf";
arguments[4] = "\"scale=120:-1\"";
```

I believe `ffmpeg` expects the filter arguments to be inside double-quotes.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your suggestion, but it did not work, just exit the app without any error even just like before. Just that if I remove the -vf parameter, the code runs fine and creates the video.